# How to disable all actions in delphi form

Tags: windows, delphi

I have a form with some actions.
I need to disable all actions when I call my LogOff procedure.
How I have to do?

Comment: Do you know how to disable 1 action? Do the same for each action you want to disable. It's almost certainly not a good idea to disable ***all*** actions. (Especially considering you may want to enable them again after a login _action_; and the enabled/disabled state probably depends on more than just "IsUserLoggedIn".)

Comment: Just disable the whole form with `form1.enabled := false`

Answer (score 9):

If by "actions" you mean that you use ActionList then set it's `State` to `asSuspended`. Per [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Actions.TActionListState) then:

> The actions in the action list do not respond when client objects tell them to "fire". The Enabled property for all actions in the list is unchanged

Answer (score 4):

**If you Using " ActionList " you can try :**

```
ActionList1.State:=asSuspended;
```

this will suspend all actions in the ActionList.

if you want to enable it again use :

```
ActionList1.State:=asNormal;
```

**if you using " ActionManager " you can use the same way :**

```
ActionManager1.State:=asSuspended;
```

if want to enable it again :

```
ActionManager1.State:=asNormal;
```

Good Luck.